# React. How to capture onMouseOver event on the parent div?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, mouseevent, mouseover

So, I trying to capture the `mouseOver` event that placed on the global parent div `list` (that contains a several nested divs `status` with childs) only for specific divs witch have `title` attribute.

But instead to get this event on `divs` with `title` attr, I always capture my `mouseOver` event only on the max depper `<i>` tag in this parent `div`.

I will be glad for any help. Thanks

My code example:

```
  <div className={list} onMouseOverCapture={e => this.catchMouseOver(e)}>
    //... some other divs that does not play any role in this example
    <div className={status1} title={'100%'}>
      <div className={security}>
        <i className={sprite} />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className={status2} title={'20%'}>
      //... A lot of such divs with child divs like the first one `status1` div
    <div className={statusN} title={'0%'}>
  </div>
```

My onMouseOverScript:

```
const getTooltipContainer = ({ target }) => {
  const aim = target.hasAttribute('title') && target
  console.log('target', aim ) // but it does not return div with `title` attribute, 
                              // only last max depper children div instead
}
```

Comment: You could try [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events): none; to child elements

Comment: Thank you! It's not a pretty solution, but it works :)  @anttud